# How to enter 3D matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

How to enter 3D matrix in Matlab?

Is the only way is with `cat` function, like this:

```
cat(3, [1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5], [0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5], ...
    [6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3])
```

may be it is possible to with brackets and semicolons?

Comment: `cat(3,....` is the best option. But you could pre-allocate like `A = zeros(4,4,2)` and then `A(:,:,1) = rand(4); A(:,:,2) = magic(4)` or else use `reshape`: `reshape(magic(4), 4, 2, 2)`

Comment: Probably other options would have been mentioned here: http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use assignment to slices:

```
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5];
A(:,:,2) = [0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5];
A(:,:,3) = [6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3];
```